# Uncaught ReferenceError: _wrapNativeSuper is not defined

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, maplibre-gl

i have a project built in react 17 version using node 14.15.5. When I install maplibre-gl version 3.6.2, this error is showing in console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: _wrapNativeSuper is not defined

I also tried installing old versions of maplibre-gl to solve this problem